# Second dropdown is not appearing straight away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a two dropdown menus, the second drop down menu appears depending on what is selected in the first dropdown menu. Problem is that in some browsers, if something is selected in the first dropdown menu, then if I click on the second dropdown menu then a dropdown does not occur, but if I select something in the first dropdown menu again and then click on the second dropdown menu, then the dropdown appears in the second dropdown menu. Why is this happening?

In Internet Explorer, Firefox and Safari, my second drop down menu appears straight away when I click on it after selecting something on the first dropdown menu for the first time.

In google chrome and opera, I have to select options from the first dropdown menu twice to be able to get the second dropdown menu working.

The jquery code for the second dropdown menu is below:

```
    var OptDrop = new Array();

    OptDrop.abc = ["",1,2];
    OptDrop.abcd = ["",1,2,3];
    OptDrop.abcde = ["",1,2,3,4];
    OptDrop.trueorfalse = [1];
    OptDrop.yesorno = [1];

    $("#optionDropId").change(function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $("#numberDropId").html("");
        $.each(OptDrop[selectedValue], function(x,y){
            $("#numberDropId").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", y).html(y));
        });
 });
```

The full code is in Jsfiddle. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XZ7um/2/) (the full code might not work fully in JSfiddle but it works in browsers on its own file and the full code shows the order of my code.

Update of the code:

What I have put in my code;

```
$("#optionDropId").change(function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $("#numberDropId").html("");
    $.each(OptDrop[selectedValue], function(x,y){
        $("#numberDropId").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", y).html(y));
    });

}); 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#optionDropId").change();
});
// this does not allow the second dropdown to work, I tried moving this code around but can't get dropdown to work when including this code
```

Comment: that is because your jquery code is being run from inside the `getDropDown` function.. so it must runs once before it will do its binding.. (*and you will ofcourse bind an additional instance each time you re-run it..*)

Comment: Please don't edit other people's answers to add your code.  Instead, please edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: Sorry bout that, I have put the update in my question, I won't put an update in somebody's answer anymore. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

The jquery .change event is not fired on pageload because it relies on underlying javascript events and the selection of the first option in a list on pageload is not a javascript selection, it's default behaviour.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#optionDropId").change();
});
```

That should trigger the .changeevents which you've assigned, be sure to call it after your .change assignment block

Comment: so are you saying replace this: "$("#optionDropId").change(function(){" to what you have mentioned?

Comment: Nope, we're keeping both bits of code, your code works fine on updating the second drop down when the .change event is fired, what my little bit of code does is it artificially fires the change event, causing the code that you've assigned to that event to run.
Check out the jquery documentation for the change function:
[http://api.jquery.com/change/].
You're using the first version of the function and I'm using the third

Comment: the link to the jquery documentation can't find the page. I will edit your answer in 1 minute to show what I have done with both bits of code so hopefully I am doing what you have told me to do.

Comment: it is linking to you account page, where am I suppose to go from there?